# Simple 2-column navigation with CSS and a single list?

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists, multiple-columns

I am looking to make a two-column navigation bar by using a single `<ul>` with six `<li>` items:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Team</li>    
    <li>Store</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>​
```

Three elements on one side, and three on the other; ordered vertically.

Right now, it's easy to do when making two seperate `<ul>` elements and putting padding/margins between them: http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/SJcjN/ — but that's not a great solution.

Could also wrap `<span>` tags around each set of three `<li>`'s — but is that the only CSS solution?

Looking for some elegant ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Team</li>    
  <li>Store</li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 0; 
}
```

They will order like that:

```
Home About
Team Store
Blog Contact
```

If that's not a problem, you have a very simple solution.

EDIT:

```
li:nth-child(even) {
  width: 50%;
  float: right; 
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

This will order them in the correct way. not sure how IE will act, but will work in all other browsers.

or you can follow strictly the `UL-LI` concept, so your html will look like this an you can have as many column as you need:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menuitem">
       <li class="column">
          <ul>               
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Team</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="column">
          <ul>               
             <li>Store</li>
             <li>Blog</li>
             <li>Contact</li>
          </ul>
        </li>               
    </ul>

    <ul class="menuitem">
        <li class="column">
          .....
        </li>
    </ul>      

</nav>
```

Making a correct and well formated html can make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks, but yep, that is a problem — in this case I could re-order them, but as this will responsive: the order will be different/bad when it widens.

Comment: Getting creative? Nice. Thanks! Could also do this with `<span>`'s then just to be sure it works in IE...?

Comment: I think I'll use your first solution for now, as my one (take a look at the other answer) works easily, but isn't valid HTML.

Comment: many ways to make it work :) but not following the rules sooner or later there will be some problems :) Keep it clean and your will get a pay out.

Comment: You're right. Also, I'm not sure your second suggestions for a `ul` within a `ul` will work in my case — it is a responsive design, and when the `li` are not in 2-3 columns, they will appear in a single line. Also, when styles are disabled, it might look weird, i.e. isn't 100% semantically correct?

Comment: You know better your design ... so you can choose what's good for you ... these things are just ideas and they might be redesigned, combined and etc. depending on your design ... just ideas to start with :) good luck ... your imagination and some testing will do the rest :)

Comment: Thank you. I always feel bad for not giving someone's idea a try if they take their time to share it with me :P (Pretty new here.)

Answer (score -1):

I think that using `<span>`'s might be the most cross-browser friendly solution.

**Unless someone has other ideas?** Looking for something cross-browser compatible, as sadly IE doesn't support `nth-child(N)`.

This is not as clean (HTML wise) as I wanted, with these random spans, but here is the HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<span>
<li>Home</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>Team</li>
</span><span>
<li>Store</li>
<li>Blog</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</span>
</ul>
</nav>
```

(Notice the `span` inside the `ul` — big faux pas in my book.)

And the CSS:

```
nav span {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

But that's hardly a good solution... any other ideas?