# two columns for dynamic drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I want to make a two columns drop down menu like this.

```
Main Menu 1 | Main Menu 2 | Main Menu 3
Sub Menu 1 | Sub Menu 5
Sub Menu 2 | Sub Menu 6
Sub Menu 3 | Sub Menu 7
Sub Menu 4
```

Here is my code.

```
<style>
ul{
list-style:none;
}
li{
float:left;
}
li li {
width:50%;
}
</style>
<ul>
<li><a href="link1.html" target="_self">Main Menu 1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="sub1.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="sub2.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="sub3.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="sub4.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="sub5.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
<li><a href="sub6.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
<li><a href="sub6.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="link2.html" target="_self">Main Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self" >Main Menu 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

But if I use float left, it becomes this.

```
Main Menu 1 | Main Menu 2 | Main Menu 3
Sub Menu 1 | Sub Menu 2
Sub Menu 3 | Sub Menu 4
Sub Menu 5 | Sub Menu 6
Sub Menu 7
```

How can I make it by CSS or Query? Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to stick to just HTML, you can either reorder your list items to fall in alternating order:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="sub1.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="sub5.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
<li><a href="sub2.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="sub6.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
<li><a href="sub3.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="sub7.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
<li><a href="sub4.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Which isn't great, but works.

Or, you can separate the list into two lists (also not the best solution).

```
<ul class="col1">
<li><a href="sub1.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="sub2.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="sub3.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="sub4.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="col2">
<li><a href="sub5.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
<li><a href="sub6.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
<li><a href="sub6.html" target="_self">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

If your content is generated elsewhere, or you're unable to adjust your lists for some reason, A List Apart has a good article on this: http://alistapart.com/article/multicolumnlists

Answer (score 0):

The answer: google it. "CSS multi-level navigation" brought me 29 800 000 results.

- http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/
- http://alistapart.com/article/dropdowns
- http://speckyboy.com/2013/01/30/more-responsive-navigation-solutions/
- http://www.noupe.com/css/multilevel-drop-down-navigation-menus-examples-and-tutorials.html
- http://woork.blogspot.be/2009/09/how-to-implement-perfect-multi-level.html
- http://geek.ryanhellyer.net/products/suckerfish_css/

And tons of others.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
In fact, I can make the multi-level navigation. But I want make a two-columns navigation and dont want the two columns becomes left right left right like my example. Any ideas?

Comment: In that case, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104818/simple-2-column-navigation-with-css-and-a-single-list . You just need to embed that in  your submenu