# How can I make two columns in DropDownList?

Tags: html, css

I have two columns in DropDownList. so, i use  this code:

```
<select name="dd1New" id="ddlNew2">
    <option class="rightddl">1</option>
    <option class="leftddl">2</option>
</select>
```

and this css code:

```
.leftddl
{
width: 50px;
height: 100px;
background-color:#0000ff;
float: left;
}

.rightddl
{
width: 50px;
height: 100px;
background-color:#00ff00;
float: right;
}
```

it's not working.

and this:

```
<select name="dd1New" id="ddlNew2">
    <div class="rightddl">
        <option>1</option>
    </div>
    <div class="rightddl">
        <option>2</option>
    </div>
</select>
```

Also, this code does not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [two columns for dynamic drop down menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391545/two-columns-for-dynamic-drop-down-menu)

Comment: Try using `<ul><li>option 1</li></ul> <ul><li>Option 2</li></ul>` form.

Comment: I've read articles. but, How do I use the <ul><li>...</li></ul> in DropDownList?

Comment: @user3717128: can you show your output you want?

Answer (score -1):

You can use column settings in css.

```
.rightddl{
column-count:2;
-moz-column-count:2; 
-webkit-column-count:2; 
}
```

[you can find more information on this link.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Comment: I do not use the CSS3 in my project